# Update a specific row in a Room Database of Android

Tags: android, android-room

I am new to Android and need some help.

I have a `listView` with some `edittext` fields and buttons and store the information of the `edittext` in a room database.
Looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyAOb.jpg

Now, when I change the input of `field A` to, let's say `AAAA`, and click on the "button", the room database has to update the row.

My question is when exactly do I call the `update` command, and how does room know which row has changed? I don't want to update to whole table.

Let me know if I should explain it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution which works for me.

```
  TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Dao_db.update(s.toString()); 

        }

    };

    viewHolder.bearbeiten_et.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

I use this Textwatcher (didn't know that something like this exist) and update my db when the text changed. :)